# Running 10.11 in VM Ware Fusion with 10.10 Host

Tags: vmware, macos

I run 10.11 public beta in a VM with VMware Fusion 7.1.2 with my rMBP 2015. I have the problem that main part in Finder or the maps in Maps.app are blank. Sidebars and menus are all rendering fine. Is this a known issue? Can I do something about this?

Comment: I presume you mean 10.11 & 10.10 host?

Comment: Yes, you a right! Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

El Capitan is a beta software and VMware Fusion 7.1.2 doesn't support El Capitan officially.

Just download and install [VMware Fusion Technology Preview 2015](https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/fusion/vmware-fusion-technology-preview-2015) and try your luck.

Improvements among others:

- New OS Support including Windows 10 Insider Preview and El Capitan Beta
- DirectX 10 and OpenGL 3.3 Support